# Raspberry Pi and LIN Bus

Tags: serial, uart, communication, lin-bus

I want to implement a [LIN Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Interconnect_Network#LIN_message_frame) using a Raspberry Pi 3.

The RPi will be the master controlling slaves on the LIN Bus.

My idea is to use the Raspberry Pi UART, but I am not sure to what extent this idea could work since RPI UART works with bytes and LIN break field range is from 13 to 26 bits.

I wanted to know if somebody have a better Idea? Has someone worked with the LIN Bus and Raspberry Pi before?

I'm thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: It would be great if you could add links to information on the LIN bus – makes it easier for folks who would like to help.

Comment: Not Pi specific.  Any machine with a UART would have a similar answer.

Comment: You might find [Use RPi as a LIN Master to control slave nodes](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13487/use-rpi-as-a-lin-master-to-control-slave-nodes) helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use RPi as a LIN Master to control slave nodes](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13487/use-rpi-as-a-lin-master-to-control-slave-nodes)

Comment: BTW, I have added an [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/82708/33476) to the duplicate question, could you check it out and tell me if it helps?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, since I am a little bitte in a hurry to finish my project,  I decided to use a Carberry shield which has a LIN bus tranceiver to connect my RPI to slave nodes. If you want to learn more about this shieldn here is the link http://www.carberry.it/en/p/374/Carberry/